# Why does this Punnet square fail?

Tags: python

This is part of my program for generating punnet squares. It should separate a "genome" of the form [['A','a'],['b','b'],['C',C']...] into possible gametes:

```
def gene_erator2(gen):
    gam = [[], []]
    q = 0
    for x in gen:
        q = q + 1
        if q > 1:
            gamgam = gam[:]
            for z in gam: 
                gamgam.append(z)
            gam = gamgam[:]
        for y in range(len(gam)):
            if y < len(gam)/2:
                gam[y].append(x[0])
            else:
                gam[y].append(x[1])
    return gam
```

When I execute

```
gene_erator2([['A','a'], ['B','b'], ['X','Y']])
```

I get

```
[['A', 'B', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], ['a', 'B', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], ['A', 'B', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], ['a', 'B', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], ['A', 'B', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], ['a', 'B', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], ['A', 'B', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], ['a', 'B', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']]
```

instead of the expected

```
[['A', 'B', 'X'], ['a', 'B', 'X'], ['A', 'b', 'X'], ['a', 'b', 'X], ['A', 'B', 'Y'], ['a', 'B', 'Y'], ['A', 'b', 'Y'], ['a', 'b', 'Y']]
```

....What? I mean, just What?

EDIT:
I now know the function that does what I want thanks to Shang, but I still want to know what was wrong with my code....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function that does what you want in the standard library.

```
import itertools

def gene_erator2(gen):
    return itertools.product(*gen)
```

This returns an iterator, which lets you iterate over all the combinations.

```
>>> i = gene_erator2([['A','a'],['B','b'],['X','Y']])
>>> list(i)
[('A', 'B', 'X'), ('A', 'B', 'Y'), ('A', 'b', 'X'), ('A', 'b', 'Y'), ('a', 'B', 'X'), ('a', 'B', 'Y'), ('a', 'b', 'X'), ('a', 'b', 'Y')]
```

Comment: I KNEW IT! HAHAH! But I wouldn't be me if I didn't still want to know what was wrong with my code...

Answer (score 1):

Beside the best solution is presented by shang, there are lot of mistakes in your code. Some of them are:

### **I**

```
     gamgam = gam[:]
    for z in gam: 
        gamgam.append(z)
    gam = gamgam[:]
```

i believe this is a doubling of the `gam` list, but in line `gamgam.append(z)` you are appending another reference to the same sublist, so result will contain lot of reference to pair of initial sublists.

### **II**

***upd** : this marked not as mistake, as `gam` size is not increasing during cycle*

```
 if y < len(gam)/2:
```

len(gam) in this condition will increase while you are appending elements to gam, so it wouldn't work as you supposed to.

So despite the ugliness of the whole solution with correction of these two this code will work properly:

```
def gene_erator2(gen):
    gam = [[], []]
    q = 0
    for x in gen:
        q = q + 1
        if q > 1:
            gamgam = gam[:]
            for z in gam:
                gamgam.append(z[:])
            gam = gamgam[:] 
        lenGam = len(gam)
        for y in range(lenGam):
            if y < lenGam/2:
                gam[y].append(x[0])
            else:
                gam[y].append(x[1])
    return gam
```

**UPD:**
As requested this is some kind of pythonic recode the `itertools.product`:

```
def product(collections):
    if collections:
        for subproduct in product(collections[1:]):
            for element in collections[0]:
                yield list(element) + subproduct

    else: yield []

def gene_erator2(gen): return list(product(gen))
```

also it's recommended to use tuples rather than lists in situations like that.

Comment: Oh. Right. Ok. I see what I did. Thanks for your help, Though what you cited as a  "mistake II" was utterly mistakeless, even if it was slightly less elegant than your proposition. (python does not reevaluate range(len(gam)) every time it iterates) You also said that this solution was ugly; how would you do it without itertools? (If the ugly comment was referring to the fact that I wasn't using itertools, then nevermind)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve the problem, without using `itertools.product`:

```
def gene_erator2(args):
    result = [[]]
    for pool in args:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    return result
```

Also take a look at `itertools.product`'s [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).